# Eclipse Error - Chartboost and R variable error

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, cocos2d-x, chartboost

I am getting an error in eclipse, I have tried everything I can but its still not working, please help, the error is shown in the screenshot below

http://postimg.org/image/uiv0aq8nz/

Comment: Please include the error message as text in the question. Please also read the help pages about how to write a good question, they are linked at the top of every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clean your project.
2. Right click on your project->Properties
3. In Android tag choose the currect project build target->Apply->Ok
4. Make sure that in your xml all field's id declare as

   android:id="**@+id**/editText1"

If the above process will not work then just ask me again..

Comment: didn't work, its a problem with my src file, i changed my bundle id and all these errors occurred